# adding callback to function - always

Tags: javascript

I found myself using a weird way to add callback functions to my functions and I was wondering if there is a more generic way to add callbacks to functions, best case I would have a situation where all of my functions check the last given param for being a function and if so use it as a callback.

This is how I did it in the past:

```
var myFunc = function( obj ) {

  if ( arguments.length > 0 ) {
    if ( _.util.typeofObj( arguments[arguments.length-1] ) === Function ) {
      var callback = arguments[arguments.length-1];
    }
  }

  // some code ...

  if ( callback !== undefined ) {
    callback();
  }

};

var foo = myFunc( myObj, function(){
  alert( 'Callback!' );
});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could, if you really want to, extend Function.prototype with a .cb prototype.  Something like:

```
Function.prototype.cb = function(cb){
   var self = this;
   return function(){
      self.callback = cb || function(){};
      self.apply(self, arguments);
   }
}
```

then your code would compress to:

```
var myFunc = function(obj){
   // some code

   this.callback(); // callback will always be defined
}
```

and the call would slightly change:

```
myFunc.cb(function(){
   // callback code
})(myObj);
```

Just an idea.  You can make the syntax pretty much whatever you want.

Comment: In this case it might not matter much, however, might want to avoid using `self` since it's a global (yet not reserved) variable.

Answer (score 13):

I prefer a formal parameter:

```
var myFunc = function(obj, callback) {
   ...
}
```

This way it makes it obvious that there is a callback. You also don't have to mess around with the `arguments` object; you can just check to see if `callback` is `undefined`, and then check to see if it is of the appropriate type (`Function`).

Comment: after using the prototype solution for a few weeks now, I switched to your advice, it's just easier to read, find it to be a very important eyecatcher

Comment: @ezmilhouse yes, there's less "magic" happening because the formal parameter is obvious :)

Comment: @ezmilhouse I suggest changing the accepted answer since you mentioned that you changed your approach.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what you are trying to do here, but a way to add a callback that seems more straight forward:

```
function( obj, callback ) {
   if(callback) {
      callback();
   }
}
```

Comment: Or to cause some head-scratching, abbreviate as `callback && callback()`

Comment: @Jackob: typeof callback == "function" && callback() is cleaner